# How to set interval only on entering specific section with scroll and clear it immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, clearinterval

There is this code below, which is pretty straightforward:

1. User scrolls into some section and that section is flagged with a CSS class "view"
2. When I get to that specific section "someClsOfSection" I want to trigger adding 20 different classes to some element with setInterval
3. Whenever I scroll the condition will be fulfilled and I don't know how to clear the interval once I enter this section...
   https://codepen.io/StevaNNN/pen/GRNOLyJ here is the codepen for

```js
const isFullySeen = el =>
    el && typeof el.getBoundingClientRect === 'function'
    && el.getBoundingClientRect()['top'] +
    window.scrollY + (window.innerHeight) <= window.innerHeight + window.scrollY;
    
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('.section').each(function() {
            if (isFullySeen(this) === true) {
              $(this).addClass('in-view');
            }
            if(isFullySeen(this) && $(this).hasClass('.someClsOfSection')) {
              let tempCls = 0;
              
              let toTwentyPercent = setTimeout(function () {
                    setInterval(function () {
                        if (tempCls < 20) {
                            tempCls++;
                            $('.c100').addClass(`p${tempCls}`).animate();
                        }
                    }, 100);
              }, 1000);
              
              clearInterval(toTwentyPercent);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I suggest running `isFullySeen(this)` once and setting a variable to its return value. Calling `getBoundingClientRect()` can be an expensive operation. Also, you have a `setInterval` within a `setTimeout` and are only capturing the output of the `setTimeout`, which is why the `clearInterval` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `setTimeout()` is assigned to `toTwentyPercent`... But is cleared right after. So it never execute its callback. Additionnaly, it's the `setInterval()` that you wish to clear. So here is what I suggest you to try:

```
let tempCls = 0;

setTimeout(function () {
  let toTwentyPercent = setInterval(function () {
    if (tempCls < 20) {
      $('.c100').eq(tempCls).addClass(`p${tempCls}`);
      tempCls++;
    }else{
      clearInterval(toTwentyPercent);
    }
  }, 100);
}, 1000);
```

So here, the script will wait 1 second, then will assign a `setInterval()` to `toTwentyPercent`.

Then, every 100 ms, a class will be added to a `.c100` element. Notice the `.eq(tempCls)` to add the `p0`, `p1`, `p2`... in sequence. Without the [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method, all `.c100` element will get an added class on each interval... And on the last interval, they will all have the classes from `p0` to `p19`.

Finally, when `tempCls < 20` is false, that is the time to clear the interval.

I removed the `.animate()` because I don't know what is the intend. That method need at least one property to animate to a new value. It is pretty useles without any argument.

Comment: what I wanted is when I scroll to some specific section of the site to trigger adding 20 classes(p1...-20) to an HTML element(.c100), but the problem still remains and that is that animations are triggered on every scroll change, that's why I put all code above. Regarding .animate() its dead code I agree... Regarding .eq() is not needed for this thing I am trying to achive.

Comment: https://codepen.io/StevaNNN/pen/GRNOLyJ here is the pen for issue

Comment: btw the only thing which should be done is do tempCls =+ 1 instead tempCls++ since ++ increments scoped :)